# jQuery get source element in callback

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors, callback, jquery-callback

```
$('.myElem').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide(500, function() {
        $(this).siblings('.myOtherElem').show();
    });
});
```

The above doesn't work because `$(this)` is no longer in correct scope in the callback. How do I pass my original source element into the callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your code should work.

To access `this` within an inner javascript method you might store the reference in the outer method scope:

```
$('.myElem').on('click', function() {

   var myElem = this;    
    $(this).hide(500, function() {
        $(myElem).siblings('.myOtherElem').show();
    });

});
```

However in most jQuery methods `this` is referring to the selector or element used:

```
$('.myElem').on('click', function() {
    // This refers to the clicked element
    $(this).hide(500, function() {
       // This refers to the clicked element as well 
       $(this).siblings('.myOtherElem').show();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myElem').live('click', function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide(500, function() { 
        $this.siblings('.myOtherElem').show(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myElem').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide(500);
    $(this).siblings('.myOtherElem').show();
});
```

Comment: That won't accomplish the same thing. Putting the `.show()` call in the callback ensures that it won't happen until the `.hide()` animation is completed. The code in your answer will cause them to both happen nearly simultaneously.

Comment: You could do it by using `delay`: `.delay(500).show(1)` However using the `show` callback is the better solution.